# Laravel task scheduling on shared hosting doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, cron

I have a `laravel` app and it runs on a shared hosting. I defined a `cronJob` on `cpanel` and a job on `laravel` app but it doesn't work.

app/console/kernel.php:

```
protected $commands = [
    '\App\Console\Commands\CronJob',
];


protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('CronJob:test')
             ->everyMinute();
}
```

app/console/comands/mycronjob:

```
public function handle()
{
     \App\Model::create([
            'name'=> 'foo',
            ...
      ]);
}
```

and on server the cronjob is:

```
php /path/to/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

when I test it locally by command `php artisan Cronjob:test` it works and creates the model but it doesn't work on server. can you tell what's the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Do you get any error ? Mysql connection works if you using mysql driver? Maybe this is due to mass assignment to your model? Does it have guard property in the class. Do you provide full cronjob command, looks like missing interval section like `* * * * * php... `

Comment: I can create a model elsewhere, and mass assignment work on local host, i have intervals on my cronjob but i didn't write it sorry

Comment: did you run sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /path/to/your/laravel/root/directory for all directories ?